# No expand button in custom notification on Android 10

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-10.0

I'm trying to build expandable notification with two custom views

Searching in internet says I need to use code like this

```
val r = RemoteViews(activity.packageName, R.layout.cf_watcher_notification_small)
val r2 = RemoteViews(activity.packageName, R.layout.cf_watcher_notification_big)

val n = NotificationCompat.Builder(activity, "test").apply {
    setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_develop)
    setNotificationSilent()
    setShowWhen(false)
    setAutoCancel(true)

    setCustomContentView(r)
    setCustomBigContentView(r2)
    setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
}
```

But resulting notification have no expand button that switch collapsed view to big and vice versa, and when I presss to notification nothing happens

[image]

Code without big content view

```
    setCustomContentView(r)
    //setCustomBigContentView(r2)
    setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
```

results as expected to

[image]

Code with only big content view

```
    //setCustomContentView(r)
    setCustomBigContentView(r2)
    setStyle(NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
```

results to notification **with** button I need

[image]

[image]

How to get this button?

Answer (score 1):

You must use `NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle` to make it expandable.

Example-

```
 var notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(activity, "test")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_develop)
    .setNotificationSilent()
    .setShowWhen(false)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setCustomContentView(r)
    .setCustomBigContentView(r2)
    .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
            .bigText(SOME_TEXT))
    .build()
```

You can get more info at [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded#large-style)

Comment: BigTextStyle not provide to set custom view as needed

Answer (score 0):

you can add a button to your custom layout and do expand and collapse notification with write an on click for that button and make views gone and visible